# Google Maps Javascript Api cant take coordinates from useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, google-api

I am trying to render google maps using javascipt api. It gets correctly rendered when it is statically typed like

```
const coords = { lat:0,lng:0 };
```

but when i use usestates to set coordinates , it shows an warning message that GoogleMap: center or defaultcenter property must be defined.

```
<GoogleMapReact
        
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'xxx' }}
        defaultCenter={coordinates}
        center={coordinates}
        defaultZoom={14}
        margin={[50, 50, 50, 50]}
        options={''}
        onChange={(e)=>{
          console.log(e);
          setCoordinates({lat:e.center.lat,lng:e.center.lng});
        }}
        onChildClick={''}
        
      >
```

Here is the useStates function

```
const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({});
```

Here is my Map function

```
<Map 
     setCoordinates={setCoordinates}
                
     setBounds={setBounds}
     coordinates={coordinates}
            
            />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the values

```
const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({lat: 0, lng: 0 });
```

Comment: ok ty , I also tried doing this and it seemed to work , but the yt tutorial didn't do this and it seemed to be working so i doubted my solution. Anyways thanks for the confirmation ,I will accept the solution

Comment: They probably used different version of the library in the tutorial